# ES6 modules "export ... from ..." in production

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules

So, i have a React app. There are `wrappers/` folder with `index.js` inside. I export all components in `wrappers/` folder inside this `index.js`. Here is how it looks:

```
export X from './X';
export Y from './Y';
export Z from './Z';
```

Every component exports default `ReactComponent`.

I import them with ease like this:

```
import { X, Y, Z } from './wrappers';
```

This works like a charm in `development` mode. But everything breaks in `production`.

I tried many different solutions i could find.

1. Tried to substitute `export X from './X'` with `export {default as X} from './X'`
2. Tried to add various babel plugins like [syntax-export-extensions](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/syntax-export-extensions/)
   and [transform-es2015-modules-commonjs](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/)

None of these helped me to get it to work on `production`.

Here are my webpack config files for dev and prod env:

**Dev config**

```
/* eslint-disable global-require, react/jsx-first-prop-new-line */
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
/* eslint-enable global-require, react/jsx-first-prop-new-line */

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'eval',
  entry: [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?https://localhost:3001',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/static/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      __DEV__: true,
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('development'),
      'process.env.BROWSER': true
    }),
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/utils'), 'node_modules'],
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loaders: ['json-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|otf|eot|svg|woff|woff2)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.ttf(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
      loader: 'url-loader',
    }]
  },
  node: {
    fs: 'empty',
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty'
  }
};
```

**Prod config**

```
import BabiliPlugin from 'babili-webpack-plugin';
import path from 'path';
import webpack from 'webpack';
import HtmlWebpackPlugin from 'html-webpack-plugin';
import S3Plugin from 'webpack-s3-plugin';
import ExtractTextPlugin from 'extract-text-webpack-plugin';

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-module-source-map',
  entry: './src/index',
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx', '.json'],
    modules: [path.join(__dirname, 'src/utils'), 'node_modules'],
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      'process.env.NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV || 'production'),
      'process.env.BROWSER': true,
    }),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      hash: true,
      template: './indexProd.html'
    }),
    new BabiliPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('bundle.css'),
  ],
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      test: /\.jsx?$/,
      loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
    },
    {
      test: /\.json$/,
      loaders: ['json-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.css$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.scss$/,
      loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'sass-loader']
    },
    {
      test: /\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|ttf|otf|eot|svg|woff|woff2)(\?[a-z0-9]+)?$/,
      loader: 'file-loader?name=[path][name].[ext]'
    }]
  },
  node: {
    net: 'empty',
    tls: 'empty',
    dns: 'empty'
  }
};
```

And my `.babelrc` just in case:

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "targets": { "node": 6 },
      "useBuiltIns": true
    }],
    "stage-0",
    "react"
  ],
  "plugins": ["add-module-exports", "transform-export-extensions", "syntax-export-extensions"],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "presets": ["react-optimize"],
      "plugins": [ "babel-plugin-dev-expression" ]
    },
    "development": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-class-properties",
        "transform-es2015-classes",
        "react-hot-loader/babel",
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What exactly "breaks"? What is the error you get? And no, the syntax is totally fine, you need to find the difference between your environments and fix the issue with production.

Comment: @Bergi This is there my headache lies. React throws error `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined.` It doesn't throw when i import direclty from file. Console.log with imported directly from file and with imported from index.js produces exaclty same string

Comment: I've seen this problem too. Certain imports mysteriously become undefined in production when using export-from. The same import, imported along a different path, in the same build is fine. It all works in dev. Another data-point, sometimes JEST also has the 'undefined' import problem with my export-froms. I'm generally using `export * from ...`. It's useful to know it also fails for `export Y from ...` (webpack@4.41.0 webpack-dev-server@3.2.1)

Comment: Were you able to figure out why this is happening?